# Django 2.0 - order a queryset by a field on the prefetch-related attribute

Tags: django, orm

My goal is to run a query on one model but sort the results based on a field in another model fetched via `prefetch_related`.

Suppose I have two models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
   ...some fields...

class ModelB(models.Model):
    ...some fields...
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, db_column='id')
    year = models.IntegerField()
```

I have tried:

```
ModelA.objects.filter(...).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'modelb_set',
        queryset=ModelB.objects.filter().order_by('-year'),
        to_attr="modelb_date"
    )
).order_by('-modelb_date')
```

but this fails because `modelb_date` is not a field on `ModelA`, it's a list. What I want is to order the `ModelA` queryset according to the latest associated `date` field (from `ModelB`). That is, if instance `One` of `ModelA` has a `modelb_date` attribute = `[x, y, z]` where `x.year` = `2017` and instance `Two` of `ModelA` has a `modelb_date` attribute = `[v, w]` where `v.year` = `2018` then the query would order instance `Two` before `One`.

I am using Django 2.0, python 3.6, and Oracle 12c.

Can anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: This does not makes much sense, since *one* `ModelA` will map to *multiple* `ModelB`s, so that is not a good criterion. You need to "fold" these values (for example, the *minimum*, *maximum*, etc.)

Comment: Furhthermore as for reference, one writes two underscores, so `modelb__date`.

Comment: assuming I need to get a queryset of `ModelA` sorted as described do I need to do something more complicated using an extra query and `Case` and `When`?

Comment: No, just annotation with `Min(..)`, and then order by the annotation.

Comment: I'm confused; `Min` would only work on fields of `ModelA`, right? And I'm trying to find the `Min` of a field on `ModelB`. I can do this with `RawSQL` but it just runs quite slow...

Comment: No, there is a difference between *annotation*, and *aggregation*.

Comment: But instead of asking *how* to do something, perhaps you first need to make it more clear *what* you want.

Comment: the annotation with `Min` works; thanks much--I learned something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to order by some value of a related model, with a *one-to-many* relation, then you need some sort of way to first "*fold*" that related data: for example taking the *minimum*, *maximum* (and depending on the type of the data, *sum*, *average*, etc. might also be valid options).

If we for example want to sort the `ModelA`s depending on the *minimum* `date` of the related `ModelB` items, then we can use an `.annotate(..)` and `.order_by(..)` combination, like:

```
ModelA.objects.filter(...).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'modelb_set',
        queryset=ModelB.objects.filter().order_by('-year'),
        to_attr="modelb_date"
    )
).annotate(
    first_date=Min('modelb__date')
).order_by('-first_date')
```

So here we will sort the `ModelA`s with the `first_date` in *descending* order, and `first_date`, is the lowest `date` for a related `ModelB`.

Comment: Does not work for Django - 2.2.14.

For the case here:

'first_date' field does not exist for ModelA error will arise.

Comment: @TusharMittal: that is likely because you did not work with `.annotate(...)` correctly. Note that you need to `.annotate(..)` the `ModelA` model, not the `Prefetch`ing.

Comment: Okay, the mentioned answer here, does not work. The question is still unresolved. If we want to sort on base of field in another model with ModelA Left Outer Join with ModelB.
How do we do that?
At the very end raw SQL seems the only option.

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem
In your answer, is there a typo?
`annotate(first_date=Min('modelb__date'))`

You are referring to the `to_attr` in Min, right?
`annotate(first_date=Min('modelb_date'))`

You mean: 
`Min('modelb_date')` or `Min('modelb__date')`
Like 1 or 2 underscores?

Comment: @TusharMittal: no, not to `to_attr`, `modelb__date` (with two underscores), refers to the `date` field of `modelb`. Did you set a `related_name` in the `ForeignKey` from *B* to *A*?

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem. Thanks for the reply. Yes, that works. But in my case I need to find Count of the prefetched related row which has `to_attr`. Something like `annotate(first_date=Count('modelb_date'))` using `to_attr`. I need to work on the prefetched related row, in the same query. Is that possible? Or will I need the another query for that.

Comment: @TusharMittal: but the number of related rows is simply `annotate(first_date=Count('modelb'))`, since we do not filter anything. You can not work with `Prefetch`, since these are done in another query: a prefetch will first fetch the `ModelA`s, and then all related `ModelB`s in one extra query.

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem Thanks again for the reply. Yes, In my case, I have something like: `queryset=ModelB.objects.filter(user=request.user)` , I need to work with `Prefetch` and the filtered queryset. That is why I need to query using the `to_attr` and order_by using the ModelB field. Have searched much for this, I think another query will be required.